# How to apply Disjoint Set Union in the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

(1 point) Suppose you have a set of N people who all do not know each other, and you have to process
a sequence of queries of the following kinds:
Type 1: MakeFriends(x,y) - x and y become friends with each other
Type 2: AreFriends(x,y) - output 1 if x and y are friends, and output 0 otherwise
In particular, for every pair of people, we need to maintain a state indicating whether they are friends
or not, and update this state based on queries of type 1, and report the state for queries of type 2.
Since you have learned about the disjoint sets data structures in your algorithms course, you decide to
store the set of N people as N singleton sets to begin with. For each query of type 1, you perform a
union operation, and for each query of type 2, you perform a find operation.
What can you say about this algorithm?
A. It may not always produce an accurate answer.
B. It works with O(lg∗n), O(lg∗n) amortized response time to both queries.
C. It works with O(n), O(n) worst-case response time to both queries.
D. The correctness of the approach depends on how DSU is implemented.

If we get the following sequence of queries: MakeFriends(1,2), MakeFriends(2,3), AreFriends(1,3), the answer to the last query with our approach (irrespective of how DSU is implemented)
will be 1, while the correct answer is 0.

Is the above explanation correct

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine two sets `S1` and `S2`, where `S1` contains elements `1, 2, 3`, and `S2` contains elements `4, 5, 6`. These two sets don't have any elements in common, so they're ***disjoint***.

Each set can be viewed as a tree that has a single root. Let's say the root of `S1` is `1` and the root of `S2` is `4`.

Now if `UNION(2, 5)` is called, it will essentially merge set `S1` with set `S2`. In other words, all the elements will now be part of a single set, and the root can be either `1` or `4` depending on the implementation. If `FIND(1,6)` is called afterwards, it will return `true`, as `1` and `6` now belongs to the same set, even though there weren't any calls like `UNION(1,6)` that explicitly asked to join `1` and `6`.

> If we get the following sequence of queries: MakeFriends(1,2), MakeFriends(2,3), AreFriends(1,3), the answer to the last query with our approach (irrespective of how DSU is implemented) will be 1, while the correct answer is 0.

Coming back to this statement, `MakeFriends(1,2)` will create a set that includes the elements `1, 2`. Calling `MakeFriends(2, 3)` will include `3` in the same set. As a result, `AreFriends(1,3)` will return true, even though there weren't any explicit calls that joined `1` and `3`, similar to the example mentioned above. So this statement is correct.

In the multiple choice questions, `A. It may not always produce an accurate answer` is correct.